# What should be the return type of this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

Currently I am performing `join` on two tables, the result could be multiple rows.

The return type is `IList<string>` currently but I am getting an error

**Error:**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>
```

Here is my expression

```
public IList<string> GetPendingSubGroups()
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var pendingSubGroup =
            db.sys_Log_Account_SubGroups.Where(subGroup => subGroup.cAuthorizedStatus.Equals("Pending")).Join(
                db.sys_Account_Primary_Groups, subGroup => subGroup.nGroupCode, group => group.nGroupCode,
                (subGroup, group) => new
                                         {
                                             cSubGroupName = subGroup.cSubGroupName,
                                             cAddedBy = subGroup.cAddedBy,
                                             dAddedOn = subGroup.dAddedOn
                                         }).ToList();
        return pendingSubGroup;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You are creating a list of an anonymous type. How are you planning on creating a string from each instance?

Comment: You have the projection which creates objects with three attributes (cSubGroupName, cAddedBy, dAddedOn). How are you expecting these objects become strings?

Comment: @Lee I understood it now , I will now create a class to represent my result.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class to represent your result

```
public class SubGroup
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string AddedBy {get; set;}        
    public DateTime AddedOn {get; set;}
}
```

And return a list of that class

```
public IList<SubGroup> GetPendingSubGroups()
    {
        using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var pendingSubGroup = db.sys_Log_Account_SubGroups.Where(subGroup => subGroup.cAuthorizedStatus.Equals("Pending")).Join(db.sys_Account_Primary_Groups, subGroup => subGroup.nGroupCode, group => group.nGroupCode,(subGroup, group) => new SubGroup
            {
                Name = subGroup.cSubGroupName,
                AddedBy = subGroup.cAddedBy,
                AddedOn = subGroup.dAddedOn 
            }).ToList();  
            return pendingSubGroup; 
        }
    }
```

note this change buried in the linq

```
(subGroup, group) => new *SubGroup*
            {
                Name = subGroup.cSubGroupName,
                AddedBy = subGroup.cAddedBy,
                AddedOn = subGroup.dAddedOn 
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution I will try this.I understood what I was doing wrong.Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) using the `Select` projection method here:

```
new
{
    cSubGroupName = subGroup.cSubGroupName,
    cAddedBy = subGroup.cAddedBy,
    dAddedOn = subGroup.dAddedOn 
}
```

The type is created by the compiler (as a class with read-only properties). The property names in this instance are `cSubGroupName`, `cAddedBy`, and `dAddedOn`.

If you need to return a `string`, perhaps you need to return one of these properties instead of the entire type?

You won't be able to implement a conversion between an anonymous type and string, so you'll likely need to either not create the type in the first place, just select the string property.

If you need to return a type and not just a `string`, then simply create a custom class with this properties and instead of making an anonymous type, make an instance of your class, as in [NinjaNye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11719992/358221).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I think I will go with NinjaNye's solution as I need all the properties ie cSubGroupNane,cGroupName,cAddedBy,dAddedOn.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error message pretty much says it all, you're returning a list of anonymous types:

```
(subGroup, group) => new
{
    cSubGroupName = subGroup.cSubGroupName,
    cAddedBy = subGroup.cAddedBy,
    dAddedOn = subGroup.dAddedOn 
}
```

If you just want the SubGroupName:

```
(subGroup, group) => subGroup.cSubGroupName
```

Comment: Ya I understood the mistake , I need all the three properties , so do you think NinjaNye's solution is helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The return type is an anonymous type.  You should create a new class with those properties and use it like so:

```
public IList<SomeClass> GetPendingSubGroups()
    {
        using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var pendingSubGroup = db.sys_Log_Account_SubGroups
            .Where(subGroup => subGroup.cAuthorizedStatus.Equals("Pending"))
            .Join(db.sys_Account_Primary_Groups, subGroup => subGroup.nGroupCode, group => group.nGroupCode,(subGroup, group) => new SomeClass(subGroup.cSubGroupName, subGroup.cAddedBy, subGroup.dAddedOn)).ToList();  

            return pendingSubGroup; 
        }
    }
```

But it seems like you only want to return a string?  In that case you can project just that one field:

```
return pendingSubGroup.Select(p => p.cSubGroupName).ToList();
```

Comment: I need all the properties.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can return IList. But you will have to unpack it everytime you try to use it. I would not recomend to do so. It's better to define you own class on return it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I am creating a class now.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, you create an anonymous type composed by the three properties :

```
cSubGroupName 
cAddedBy 
dAddedOn
```

If **SubGroupName** is what you want to get, then you can or amend your qu

```
public IList<string> GetPendingSubGroups()
        {
            using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var pendingSubGroup = db.sys_Log_Account_SubGroups.Where(subGroup => subGroup.cAuthorizedStatus.Equals("Pending")).Join(db.sys_Account_Primary_Groups, subGroup => subGroup.nGroupCode, group => group.nGroupCode,(subGroup, group) => subGroup.cSubGroupName).ToList();  
                return pendingSubGroup; 
            }
        }
```